# Test for Empty file when using the DataTable.ReadXml() method

Tags: c#, datatable, xmlreader

So I am using the `DataTable.ReadXml()` method described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx)
like so:

```
DataTable actions = new DataTable();
string myfile = @".\MyFile.xml"
actions.ReadXml(file);
```

but if .\MyFile.xml is an empty file the method crashes.. how can I test whether the file is empty before passing it to the `ReadFile()` method

Comment: Use a StreamReader and check the files content? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file length before reading, as

```
// Create new FileInfo object and get the Length.
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
long s1 = f.Length;
```